# Searching Query in codeigniter with timestamp format

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter, date

how do i compare date and time in codeigniter query where the database cell format is timestamp. i need to search data between date and between time. but date and time in my database in timestamp format. i have 4 inputs with datepicker and timepicker. datepicker format like "2017-06-06", and timepicker format like "16:00:00".  my database timestamp format looks like "2017-06-06 16:35:00.256". how do i compare my date and times with timestamp? big thanks for your help. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Put the time and date together then use `between` for the query. An insecure approach just for demonstration `where '{$_POST['date']} {$_POST['time']}' between startdate and enddate` assuming `startdate` and `enddate` are columns you want to compare against. You should parameterize that though.

Comment: just concatenate your datepicker value to your timepicker value and do it in your query

Comment: @chris85 i tried like this one: $start_date = $firstdate.$firsttime;
        $end_date = $lastdate.$lasttime;
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('history'); 
        $this->db->where('InsertAt BETWEEN "'.$start_date. '" and "'. $end_date.'"'); but its not working. im sorry im a newbie.

Comment: Does it throw an error or just no results found? Output `'InsertAt BETWEEN "'.$start_date. '" and "'. $end_date.'"'` what is it?

Comment: @chris85 its work. some wrong code in my ajax and i fixed it.  its done. thanks for your help.

Comment: thanks @AdhanTimothyYounes

Comment: @Djoe did it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $start_date = date('Y-m-d'); //lets date this was your date

    //it would be something like below  
    $query = $this->db->query(
        "SELECT FROM tbl_event WHERE event_startdate <= '{$start_date}'
        AND event_enddate >= '{$end_date}'");
```